# Git: delete files in a branch, what happens when a merge takes place

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm relatively new to source control (at least complex source control).

If I'm developing a set of features in a branch, and I happen to delete some cruft out of the source tree in this branch, what happens when I merge? Are the files properly deleted in the trunk/master?

Is there anything I should avoid doing that is typically problematic when developing in a branch?

This is a 2-3 developer system, so we're not talking about massive changes to source. I'm told you should pull from the trunk often to avoid tangled manual merge situations, and this makes sense.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git is a content-based system, not a file-based system. Deleting a file is roughly the same as deleting a couple of lines in a file. The merge should proceed quite normally, and will require some conflict resolution if someone else edited the content that you deleted.